# Can I use a monadic action to filter Fold from Control.Lens?

Tags: haskell, lenses, haskell-lens

Control.Lens.Fold contains `filtered`, which I could use to filter a list before applying some monadic action. There doesn't seem to be a corresponding `filteredM` - but is there a way to get that effect?

To be clear, say I have

```
xs      :: [ MyType ]
predM   :: MyType -> MyMonad Bool
actionM :: MyType -> MyMonad ()
```

how can I apply `actionM` to each element of `xs` for which `predM` returns `True`?

An important constraint is that I want to sequence all invocations of `predM` before the first invocation of `actionM` - so I need a way to make two passes over the list. I can't just combine `predM` and `actionM` into a single function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why not

```
mapM_ actionM <=< filterM predM $ toListOf YOUR_LENS_HERE YOUR_OBJECT_HERE
```

or just

```
mapM_ actionM <=< filterM predM $ xs
```

if you really only need to work on a list

Comment: Well, I don't actually have just a list - I may have oversimplified. I actually have a Traversal, from control.lens.traversal

Comment: `toListOf :: Traversal' s a -> s -> [a]` will give you list.